# Placement of buttons

Tags: buttons, labels, call-to-action, position

I am designing a pop up which will come up after the user has set of a chain of commands.

We have a group of 10 items and the first one that can be picked by the client gets processed automatically after a button is pressed.

Now I want to ask what should happen with the other 9 items which are in the same group.

They can be processed automatically, one by one by the user or not at all.

I am not sure about the label of the buttons and the positioning!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This seems to be a mix of questions, button placement as well as what action to take with the other processes. Can you clarify what exactly youre asking? Also I would consider changing the modal text to "would you like to process this automatically or something similar, to me pressing a button to continue *automatically* seems paradoxical and self-contradictory.

Comment: If the client picked 1 of the item from Group of 10, it indicate that client is selecting individual item to change one-by-one. If the group item has checkboxes with "select all" option, then client can select 10 item to change all the 10 items either "automatic" or "manual". Also, correct me if I am wrong, can we flip the current button placement

Comment: Personally, I'd look toward the bottom right for all of my options, as that is standard behavior on Windows (and other) dialogs. I'd at least expect the buttons to be evenly spaced, if they were not right-aligned. In your image, I looked to the bottom right first, and had to look back to the left to see the "yes" option.

Comment: **Text:** 9 commands queued for execution. **Button1:** Run All Commands. **Button2:** Run Next Command. **Button3:** Cancel Remaining Commands

Comment: How about a check box for "Do this action for the next X items"

Comment: It my case the webapp has found several other entries that look the same and can most probably be connected to one big entry, so it offers the possibility to try to add them automatically for the users benefit, hence the question.

Now the user can let it do automatically, or can proceed to do it one by one to check it one last time to make sure all other data is also present. 
And ofc i want to offer them the possibility to be done after they have clicked and processed that one entry they have chosen.

Answer (score 9):

As far as the buttons are concerned, I would suggest something like the attachment. I am not aware of the complete scenario though.

[image]

Comment: Where is the explicit Cancel option? The Close-X is no equivalent imo. (Hard to click, no easy keyboard access, no option for tooltip, no clear meaning..)

Comment: Dude, that was just for an idea... not the actual size or content... since I don't know the whole scenario and the options user would be choosing from, you can always press ESC for closing it. Cancel button was doing the same thing, i.e. closing it.

Comment: I approve of the button labels. The "Yes - <one thing>"/"No - <another thing>" is really confusing. If presented with such a choice, I always have to go back and re-read the question at least once to understand _what_ I am being asked. Giving enough information in the button label to be able to form a choice make a choice is really good. On the "cancel" button - it may or may not be relevant if it's present. It does depend on the context. This seems acceptable to me, yet it depends.

Comment: Please make the buttons have the same part of speech. "Automatic" is an adjective (modifies a noun), but "Manually" is an adverb (modifies an adjective or a verb).